# Is the [Linq] tag appropriate if the code doesn't use Linq?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question raises my question.

> [Classify values depending on predicates](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/77881/41243)

The code in the question doesn't actually use any [linq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linq). OP simply believes there may be a solution using Linq that is better than theirs. Is this an appropriate use of the tag? On one hand, I would think not, because the code in question doesn't use it. On the other, using the tag puts the question in front of the proper experts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the tags should describe the features of the code, and not the desires of the asker. If the code uses Linq, then go ahead and tag it. If the asker thinks the code could be done better with Linq, then they are turning the [linq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linq) tag in to a meta-tag, it's a feature of the request, not a feature of the code.

If you don't remove the tag, then I will ;-)